# How do I access all property variables stored in a C# type?

Tags: c#, types, foreach, properties, arguments

I would like to know if there is a way to determine all variables in an argument type, with all their extensions.

For example if I have something called `Kitten`

Theres `Kitten.Name, Kitten.Age Kitten.Type` etc.

How do I access all kitten things without knowing them
and have them print llke this

`"Kitten.Name = Max, Kitten.Age = 4, Kitten.Type = Siamese, Kitten.Owner = Sara"`

In this case I didn't know Sara was the owner, but now I know because I asked for all Kitten properties.

Comment: Reflection! Look at [Type.GetProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: If you want all of the data for printing purposes, don't manually loop over the properties with reflection, although that will work.  Use a serializer...serializers are perfect for taking an object structure and converting it into a format that you can easily consume elsewhere.

Comment: How do I serialize them?

Answer (score 0):

Like @itsme86 has already mentioned... With reflection.

```cs
  foreach (PropertyInfo item in userInfo
                .GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(x => x.CanRead))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}: {item.GetValue(userInfo, null)}");
            }
```